# How can I use EF Core data seed without shell commands

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an assignment, relatively simple, but for some reason that assignment turns out to be extremely dificult to implement on the Entity Framework Core.

I have to populate the data (conditionally, populate that data if that data doesn't exist). I am using a data seeding concept of the Entity Framework Core in the DB Context Class

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeTable>().HasData(new SomeTable
        {
            Property1= 5,
            Property2= "Something",
            Created = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            CreatedBy = "System",
            Modified = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            ModifiedBy = "System",
            Id = 1
        }, new SomeTable
        {
            Property1= 6,
            Property2= "Something",
            Created = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            CreatedBy = "System",
            Modified = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            ModifiedBy = "System",
            Id = 1});
         }
      }
```

This code works ONLY if you run shell commands add-migration and update-database. Is there a way for this code to work WITHOUT having to run these two commands. I simply want this code invoked when the application starts

Thank you everyone in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: @viveknuna thank you for your answer, can you please point out something specific in there that is relavand to my question? Thank you again

Comment: I don't know how your app looks like or what are you doing, but the code is executed [when the context is initialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-5.0.0).